# tcpclient continuous read and write in matlab

Tags: matlab, tcpclient

I am reading data from the a device using `read(t)` from ethernet.
Device continuously sending data over ethernet on some particular node.

I am reading this data continuously using `while` loop, giving while loop to some impossible condition to stop.

When I run my script I am not able to send any other command to device because while loop running continuously.

The program is not coming out of the while loop.

Is any way to read continuously data from Ethernet using `tcpclient` command.

Meanwhile, I am reading data from the device, how to send some commands to the device over ethernet using `write(t,stop)` command. because the script running continuously.

```
t = tcpclient("172.24.96.81",10952); 
write(t,data1); 
c=1;
while c~=1 % just to run while loop continuously
      
    data2=read(t);
    % manipulation from data2
end
```

Comment: Just as a style-note, `while 1` (or `while True` for that matter) does exactly the same, i.e. run forever until forced out.

Comment: You can delete the while loop and configure a callback instead. Something like: `configureCallback(t,"byte",64,@readmydata)`, a callback that is triggered each time that the buffer contain 64 bytes. The doc is [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tcpclient.configurecallback.html)

Comment: thanks @obchardon. this [link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/780507-too-many-input-arguments-using-built-in-configurecallback-for-tcpip-object?s_tid=answers_rc1-2_p2_MLT) is also very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
t = tcpclient("172.24.96.81",10952); 
Bytes_DATAF=t.NumBytesAvailable
configureCallback(t,"byte",Bytes_DATAF,@(varargin)readf1())
```

where `readf1()`

```
function readf1()
read(t)
end
```

for more clarity visit this [link](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tcpclient.configurecallback.html#d123e1418978) and this [link](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/780507-too-many-input-arguments-using-built-in-configurecallback-for-tcpip-object?s_tid=answers_rc1-2_p2_MLT)